# How make the header background partially transparent when scrolling down

Tags: html, css, shopify

What kind of html & CSS style is this? Please help

Link: https://buddhapowerstore.com/collections/main-page/products/feng-shui-black-obsidian-wealth-bracelet#looxReviews

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get event of scrolling and get scroll position like below.

```
window.onscroll = function(e) { 
    posY = this.scrollY;
}
```

And define a class to be added to header, like this

```
.partially_transparent {
     background-color: rgba(num, num, num, 0.5);
}
```

When on scrolling, get posY value and if it is larger than 0 or specific value, then add that class to your header.

```
if (posY > 0)
$('#header').addClass('partially_transparent');
else 
$('#header').removeClass('partially_transparent');
```

So to sum up;

```
// insert this function theme.js.liquid
window.onscroll = function(e) { 
    posY = this.scrollY;
    if (posY > 0)
      $('#header').addClass('partially_transparent');
    else 
    $('#header').removeClass('partially_transparent');
}

// insert this class to theme.scss.liquid

.partially_transparent {
     background-color: rgba(num, num, num, 0.5);
}
```